# Angular: the pipe 'filter' could not be found even after adding in imports

Tags: angular, pipe

I had been following [this](https://www.freakyjolly.com/angular-search-pipe-filter-using-ng2-search-filter-quick-example-tutorial/#.X3F_iHUzacB) website for adding the search component in my angular. I  have checked the previously posted questions but still, I am not able to figure out the solution for this error- "The pipe 'filter' could not be found ng".
Thank you for the help in advance!

Here is the code
app.module.ts

```
import { BrowserModule  } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { AppComponent } from './app';
import { SearchByEventNameComponent } from './search-by-event-name/search-by-event-name.component';
import { Ng2SearchPipeModule } from 'ng2-search-filter';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
     BrowserModule, 
     Ng2SearchPipeModule
  ],
  declarations: [AppComponent,SearchByEventNameComponent],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

search-by-event-name.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Ng2SearchPipeModule } from 'ng2-search-filter';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-search-by-event-name',
  templateUrl: './search-by-event-name.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./search-by-event-name.component.css']
})
export class SearchByEventNameComponent implements OnInit {
  }
  term: string;

  filterData = [
    {
      firstName: 'Celestine',
      lastName: 'Schimmel',
      address: '7687 Jadon Port'
    },
    {
      firstName: 'Johan',
      lastName: 'Ziemann PhD',
      address: '156 Streich Ports'
    },
    {
      firstName: 'Lizzie',
      lastName: 'Schumm',
      address: '5203 Jordon Center'
    },
    {
      firstName: 'Gavin',
      lastName: 'Leannon',
      address: '91057 Davion Club'
    },
    {
      firstName: 'Lucious',
      lastName: 'Leuschke',
      address: '16288 Reichel Harbor'
    }
  ]

}
```

search-by-event-name.component.html

```
<div class="form-group">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search Here" [(ngModel)]="term">
    </div>

    <table class="table">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th scope="col">First</th>
                <th scope="col">Last</th>
                <th scope="col">Address</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr *ngFor="let item of filterData | filter:term">
                <td>{{item.firstName}}</td>
                <td>{{item.lastName}}</td>
                <td>{{item.address}}</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

Comment: post your code...

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the code might help.

1. Have you included your Pipe in the `declarations` field of a `NgModule` metadata?
2. Is this `NgModule` the same that declares your `Component`? If not, the `NgModule` of your `Component` has to `import` the first one (that has to `export` the Pipe, too).

- https://angular.io/guide/pipes#creating-pipes-for-custom-data-transformations

Comment: Umm... I have done exactly as told in the link I followed, I have posted my code, are there any errors?

Comment: Which version of Angular are you using? Which of the library?